# Unity: Start the game on a specific monitor indicated externally

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiple-monitors

I'm developing a game in Unity that has an external launcher. For multi-monitor compatibility, I want to have the game start on the same screen as the launcher's window (the midpoint of the window if spanning multiple monitors).

I looked into the [`-monitor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlayerCommandLineArguments.html) command line argument, but the numbers didn't correspond at all to the order in which the launcher enumerated the monitors. (The launcher is an Electron app using `window.getScreenDetails()` to get the display layout.)

My next idea was to pass just the point into Unity and handle iterating the displays and going to the display that contained the specific point, only to find out that, as far as I can tell, Unity doesn't have any concept of multiple displays forming a cohesive desktop. All coordinates in the [Unity screen API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html) are relative to a specific display, neither does the [`DisplayInfo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DisplayInfo.html) class contain any information about the position of the display relative to the others.

That being said, how can I communicate to my Unity game where specifically I want it displayed?

Comment: The `Display.displays` collection might help: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiDisplay.html

Comment: @Absinthe It doesn't look like that API can tell how displays are laid out relative to one another either.

Comment: why does it matter where they are in relation - your original question was to run on the same one as the launcher

Comment: @BugFinder - It doesn't matter if there's another unambigious way to tell Unity which display I want. `Display.displays` doesn't iterate in the same order as `window.getScreenDetails()` in Electron and there's no unique IDs between the two APIs either. If there's another way to unambigously identify a specific monitor across multiple APIs other than where it is on the combined desktop, I'm open to that solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Unity you can set the monitor index using: `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("UnitySelectMonitor", index);`

It'll probably be harder to communicate the index to the Unity application itself though, there fore I'd set the index in the registry directly before starting the application. Since PlayerPrefs are located in the system registry itself that should work quite nicely. You can find OS depending locations in the API: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

I don't know for sure how to get the monitor index of this specific launcher, but quickly looking through the API my guess would be using `screen.getPrimaryDisplay()`. The Id of the return value is probably the monitor index. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/screen#screengetprimarydisplay
Otherwise have a look in the registry as well if there's a value stored for the launchers monitor index.

Comment: The `id` value in Electron's API is a ten digit integer, definitely not the 1-based indexing Unity wants. The order of the array returned by `screen.getAllDisplays()` don't match Unity's indexes either.

Comment: @MiffTheFox How do these integers look like? Is it possible that the index is somehow stored in a bit of this int, or maybe in a digit? Is there a registry key that may indicate the primary display index?
The Unity display index is equal the OS index and the OS index has to be available to Electron as well for it to function and display on the correct display. This value has to be stored somewhere...

Comment: My screen layout according to my OS is this: https://loyhargil.net/u/o6oKMB.png  Electron [enumerates these screens in the same order as the OS](https://loyhargil.net/u/tOAOEK.png) using the Chromium `getScreenDetails` API, but using Unity's `-monitor` command line option, the game starts on the center monitor (system 2, electron 1) for `1`, the left monitor (system 1, electron 0) for `2`, the right monitor (system 3, electron 2) for `4`, and the top monitor (system 4, electron 3) for `3`.

Comment: Unity starts at index 0. Could you try using index 0 to 3 and report back if it works then? I've never had an issue with an index being wrong.
The way you wrote the indices for the monitors is a bit odd, is it possible you confused the right and top monitor?

Comment: `-monitor 0` behaves as if the `-monitor` argument was unspecified and the game starts on whatever monitor it was on last. [Unity's documentation calls out that the index for the command line is 1-based.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlayerCommandLineArguments.html#:~:text=Run%20Standalone%20Player%20on%20the%20specified%20monitor%2C%20indicated%20by%20a%201%2Dbased%20index%20number.) Sorry I phrased the indexes confusingly, [Here is the list in a tabluar format.](https://loyhargil.net/u/WPaS5M.png)

Comment: Wasn't aware that the command line arg is 1 based, sorry. The entry in the registry is 0 based, thought it'd be the same. The loyhargil domain can't be reached at the moment of writing, I'll try again later. So we'd expect the correct monitor to be the electron index + 1, right?

Comment: We'd expect it, but that's not what I get. Unity's enumeration swaps the position of the left and center monitors, as well as swapping the position of the top and right monitors. Windows/Electron see Left, Center, Top, Right while Unity sees Center, Left, Right, Top. See my table: https://loyhargil.net/u/WPaS5M.png

Comment: Yeah, I see. I'm unfortunately a bit at a loss as well, I'm sorry. I tried recreating the issue on my multi-monitor systems, but here it works as expected for some reason. Granted, I didn't use the launcher you're using but rather setting it in the game options by editing the registry but the indices seem to match the system. Sorry that I couldn't help.